# Wrap multiple phone numbers in a paragraph with anchor tag

Tags: javascript

I have this code which will wrap the first phone number in this long `<p>` tag with an `<a>` tag. However if there are multiple phone numbers in the `<p>` tag it doesn't wrap all of them. How can I get every phone number in the `<p>` tag to be wrapped in an `<a>` tag without changing the markup.

The code below demonstrates how the first phone number is wrapped properly but not the rest.

```js
function phoneWrap() {
    const regex = /([(]?\d{3}[)]?[(\s)?.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{4})/
    const tag = document.querySelector("p");

    const text = tag.innerHTML.replace(regex, "<a href=\"tel:$&\">$&</a>");

    tag.innerHTML = text
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', phoneWrap);
```

```html
<div>
 
 <p>

Lorem FIRST ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.  <br /><br />

Lorem SECOND ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.  123-456-7890   <br /><br />

Lorem THIRD ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 123.456.7890  <br /><br />

Lorem FOURTH ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 123-456-7890  <br /><br />



</p>

  

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `g` at the end of the `regex`. `g` represents global here.

Like this: `const regex = /([(]?\d{3}[)]?[(\s)?.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{4})/g`

```js
function phoneWrap() {
  const regex = /([(]?\d{3}[)]?[(\s)?.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{4})/g
  const tag = document.querySelector("p");

  const text = tag.innerHTML.replace(regex, "<a href=\"tel:$&\">$&</a>");

  tag.innerHTML = text
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', phoneWrap);
```

```html
<div>

  <p>

    Lorem FIRST ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. <br /><br /> Lorem SECOND ipsum dolor sit amet,
    consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
    velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 123-456-7890 <br /><br /> Lorem THIRD ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
    eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 123.456.7890 <br /><br /> Lorem FOURTH ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
    incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 123-456-7890 <br /><br />



  </p>



</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

by default regex will get the first pattern that match your requirment and stop after that, but if you want to get all of them so all you need is to add the global flag `g`

As they said in [`MDN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/global#description)

> The "g" flag indicates that the regular expression should be tested against all possible matches in a string.

```js
function phoneWrap() {
    const regex = /([(]?\d{3}[)]?[(\s)?.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{4})/g // just add [g]
    const tag = document.querySelector("p");

    const text = tag.innerHTML.replace(regex, "<a href=\"tel:$&\">$&</a>");

    tag.innerHTML = text
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', phoneWrap);
```

```html
<div>
 
 <p>

Lorem FIRST ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.  <br /><br />

Lorem SECOND ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.  123-456-7890   <br /><br />

Lorem THIRD ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 123.456.7890  <br /><br />

Lorem FOURTH ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 123-456-7890  <br /><br />



</p>

  

</div>
```